# Divergence and curl united?

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

In my post,

In 2D we can define

$$div(F) = \lim_{C\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{A}\int_C F \cdot \hat{r} dC$$
$$curl_z(F) = \lim_{C\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{A}\int_C F \cdot \hat{v} dC$$

Where $C$ is a circle around the point under consideration, A its area, r is a normal vector to the circle, and v is a tangent vector.

Notice that the only difference between the two is the direction of the dotted vector(r or v). If it is normal to the circle we get divergence and if it is tangent we get the curl.

But what if we use a gradient of some function f?

$$\int_C F \cdot \nabla f dC$$

for some f, it is the case that we will get the div and curl.

It looks like part of the divergence theorem but I guess we need to do it in 3D.

e.g,

$$\int_V F \cdot \nabla f dV = \oint_S f F \cdot \hat{n} dS - \int_V f \nabla \cdot F dV$$

which sort of looks like a decomposition into the normal and perpendictional components... e.g., the div and curl, but not quite.

Any ideas how to interpret $$\int_C F \cdot \nabla f dC$$?

Comment: I understand the point you're making, but I'm a bit unclear on your notation. If C is a circle, what does it mean for C to approach 0?

Comment: @ZettaSuro Because the div and curl are defined at a point. C can be easily parameterized as dr<cos(t), sin(t)> and as dr->0 the circle gets smaller and smaller around the point in question.

Comment: Where is $f$ supposed to live? Is it a function on a neighborhood of the point?